# Скрипт отключен, но код в нём работает. Unity 5, C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня в скрипте есть метод OnTriggerStay2D (). **Когда я отключаю скрипт, то этот метод всё равно работает**, почему? Скрипт же отключён

Comment: А можете код показать?

Comment: Нужен только код метода?

Comment: **Note**: Trigger events will be sent to disabled MonoBehaviours, to allow enabling Behaviours in response to collisions.  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay2D.html  - оно?

Comment: Так, понятно. То - есть методы соприкосновения работают и при отключённом режиме, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @СергейМишин , случаем, это не вы поставили минус вопросу? Если это так, то чем он вам не понравился?

Comment: Нет, минус не от меня. Если я правильно понимаю документацию тоже, то триггерные события посылаются даже на выключенные скрипты, чтобы срабатывали поведения коллизии.

Comment: @СергейМишин , Окей, ясно. Спасибо что ответили на вопрос. Но можно ли сделать так, чтобы метод не работал при выключенном скрипте, но и не деактивировать коллайдер?

Comment: @RinktonGames возможно хорошим решением будет заведение булевой переменной, которая отвечает за что, что объект внутри триггера (isInTrigger). И включать/выключать её в OnTriggerEnter2D/OnTriggerExit2D.

Comment: @СергейМишин Решение оказалось проще, я просто весь метод занёс под условие, если скрипт активен, и всё. Во всяком случае, спасибо за помощь

Comment: @СергейМишин стоит оформить в виде ответа